# How to get the Object atributes from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I make a call to the server using ajax and I return the class instance .

My return ajax response looks like follows.

```
  Object { id=1362570046980 , creationDate=1362570046980, type="PUBLIC"}
```

hOw i can get the values of id  , creationDate and type from this object.

Comment: That's a bizarre data format to return. I'd strongly suggest changing the server side to return a standard data format (JSON or XML are probably best) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.` operator get the objects value.. however the obect which you are gettin is weird.. not JSON.. so make sure it is returning json

say your object is data

```
alert(data.id) //gives you 1362570046980 
alert(data.creationDate) //gives you 1362570046980 
alert(data.type) //gives you PUBLIC
```

Comment: I did this but when i did data.creationDate it gave me the data.id

Comment: @SaurabhKumar But `data.id` and `data.creationDate` are the same in your example output.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
var myobject = yourAjaxResponseObject;

alert(myobject.id);
alert(myobject.creationDate);
alert(myobject.type);
```

Map a variable to your object/response, and access it's properties, etc, in that way as described up above.

Comment: Why do you assing the response object to a variable instead of accessing it directly?

Comment: does that really matter, the thing you're asking me? :) we're here to provide solutions and help people understand things :)

Comment: Well, can you help me understand why you use the extra variable?

Comment: In other words, you have no idea yourself.

Comment: wanna challenge me? :) for 10.000 of your reputation? :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a callback function in your ajax function to which an object will be passed containing the response.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "some.php",
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" },
complete: function(data){ //This is the callback function
  alert(data.id);
  alert(data.creationDate);
  alert(data.type);
}
});
```

As you can see you can then access the properties in the json using simple dot notation.